# Relaxation time for moving charges in a medium

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

This will be a short question:

How could I show that the quotient between permittivity and conductivity $\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma_c}\right)$ is the relaxation time for moving charges in a medium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! We just need to use the Maxwell's equation: $$\left(\nabla . \vec{D}\right)=\rho$$ and the continuity equation: $$\left(\nabla . \vec{J}\right)=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

We have that,

$$\left(\nabla . \vec{D}\right)=\varepsilon\left(\nabla . \vec{E}\right)=\rho$$

and

$$\left(\nabla . \vec{J}\right)=\sigma_c\left(\nabla . \vec{E}\right)=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

So,

$$\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon}=-\frac{1}{\sigma_c}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}\Leftrightarrow p=Ae^{-\frac{\sigma_c}{\varepsilon}{t}},\hspace{5pt}A=\text{const}.$$

Then, $\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma_c}$ is the relaxation time for the moving charges.